# Strange crawl requests from google bot

Tags: google, wordpress, bot

My Wordpress web site recently had a strange crawl link from Google. This is the list of crawl errors on my Google Webmaster Tools page:

[image: Google Webmaster Tools screenshot.]

Are these normal requests from google, or has my website been hacked?

Comment: That information is not enough to tell if you're "hacked". Also, how do you know it's "from Google"?

Comment: That is report in my google webmaster tool, crawl errors section.